# global variable evaluation and decorator arguments

Tags: python, evaluation, unit-testing

I'm coding with unittest and i have question.
I want to skip test case depend on global variable.

```
import unittest

_SKIP_TEST = False
all_suites = unittest.TestSuite()

class Test1(unittest.TestCase):
    @unittest.skipIf(_SKIP_TEST, 'Test should be run')
    def runTest(self):
        global _SKIP_TEST
        _SKIP_TEST = True
        print('Test1 executed')
all_suites.addTest(Test1())

class Test2(unittest.TestCase):
    @unittest.skipIf(_SKIP_TEST, 'Test should skipped')
    def runTest(self):
        print('Test2 executed')
all_suites.addTest(Test2())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(all_suites
```

I thought test2 would be skipped after execution test1 (global variable _SKIP_TEST set to True), but both test was executed.

```
$ python test.py                                                                        
runTest (__main__.Test1) ... Test1 executed
ok
runTest (__main__.Test2) ... Test2 executed
ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

It maybe come from variable scope or evaluation timing issue, or something i dont know....
How can i make this code work as i expected?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The decorator is applied *at module import time*; by the time you set `_SKIP_TEST` to `True` that decorator has long since been applied.

You could call the [`TestCase.skipTest()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.skipTest) in the test instead:

```
class Test1(unittest.TestCase):
    def runTest(self):
        if _SKIP_TEST:
            self.skipTest(_SKIP_TEST, 'Test should be run')

        global _SKIP_TEST
        _SKIP_TEST = True
        print('Test1 executed')

class Test2(unittest.TestCase):
    def runTest(self):
        if _SKIP_TEST:
            self.skipTest(_SKIP_TEST, 'Test should be skipped')
        print('Test2 executed')
```

or write your own decorator that uses that raises the [`unittest.SkipTest()` exception](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.SkipTest) based on a *callable*:

```
from functools import wraps
from unittest import SkipTest

def dynamicSkipIf(callable, reason):
    def decorator(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def wrapper(*args, **kw):
            if callable():
                raise SkipTest(reason)
            return f(*args, **kw)
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

then use that as:

```
class Test1(unittest.TestCase):
    @dynamicSkipIf(lambda: _SKIP_TEST, 'Test should be run')
    def runTest(self):
        global _SKIP_TEST
        _SKIP_TEST = True
        print('Test1 executed')
all_suites.addTest(Test1())

class Test2(unittest.TestCase):
    @dynamicSkipIf(lambda: _SKIP_TEST, 'Test should skipped')
    def runTest(self):
        print('Test2 executed')
```

Not `_SKIP_TEST` is tested *when the test is executed* rather than at module import time.